# make work 3 divs (left, middle and right) in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have 3 divs that show correctly in chrome firefox, but, in IE, they aren't showing in the same way...

I want to display something like this

[image]

but, in IE7,IE8,IE9, I am getting:
[image]

I added the code to jsfiddle and ran it on IE and seemed to be ok, but in server it is displaying as in the above image...

What could be wrong, is there a line of code that is missing to IE?

Please take a look at my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/QcayB/2/

this is html

```
<div id="wrapper">
         <div id="header">
             <img src="http://www.astrosurf.com/re/tse_20060329_earthshine.jpg" width="500" height="478" alt=""/>
         <h1>           </h1>
         </div>

         <div id="main">

          <div id="col_izq">
            <p>
            </p><div id="usa">      
        <a id="usajq" href="#"><span class="textots">left</span></a>
        <a id="usajql" href="#"><span class="textotsl">left</span></a>
        </div>
          <p></p>
                    </div>
          <div id="col_medio">

          </div>

          <div id="col_der">
            <p>
            </p><div id="mexico">       
        <a id="usajq" href=""><span class="textotst">right</span></a>
        <a id="usajql" href=""><span class="textotslt">right</span></a>

        </div>
          <p></p>
              </div>
    </div>


   </div>
```

Comment: How does your CSS look like? Where do you include your CSS?

Comment: I include it normally as `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: Could it be that it's not closed? ` />`

Comment: Oh yeah, let me check it, I forgot IE is special

Comment: @Dharman I checked it and it is closed.... what could be wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have something like this on your page?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
```

X-UA-Compatible may also be being sent by your server in the response header.